# problem tables in epub

Tags: fixed-layout

I have to create an epub where there are many tables.

I am attaching the screen of how badly you see the tables on a cell phone. there is some solution to make the tables fit the type of mobile or ipad or computer?
[image]

[image]

as you can see, the table is cut into 2 pages. This is then a small table, but if it were bigger it would be cut even more. is there any solution?
thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What are you trying to achieve? Does this actually have anything to do with a table of contents? (It sounds like you are asking about layout tables, not a listing of the contents of the book.)

Comment: yes I was wrong to write, I refer to layout tables.
I wanted to understand if there are any additional commands I should add or change to make my epub better. In particular for the tables

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? "Better" how? Are you having problems with the epub layout? Or just checking whether you've done everything to achieve a certain result? (If the latter, *what* result are you hoping to achieve?)

Comment: first of all thanks for the availability. exactly as you say, I would like to know if I have done everything right or if I can improve something. If you are looking for this book on ebbok store:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/venous-access-a-practical-textbook/id1334086564?l=es&mt=11
 you can freely download the preview and when you get to chapter 3 you can see the work I've done and especially the tables. 
I would like to understand if there is any command I should add or change in the css style.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It would be better if you could post an example, like a screenshot, here, rather than asking people to go download a preview of a book. Also you still haven't explained *what you're trying to do.* You want to know if you "have done everything right." Okay, but what are you trying to accomplish? We can't tell you "if there is any command [you] should add or change in the css style" unless *you* tell *us* what you *want* to happen.

Comment: ok I changed the question

Comment: I have to create an epub where there are many tables.

I am attaching the screen of how badly you see the tables on a cell phone. there is some solution to make the tables fit the type of mobile or ipad or computer?